# How to hide the command line window when running OpenVPN in Python?

Tags: python

`subprocess.Popen([openvpn_path, "--config", config_file, "--service", "--quiet"])`
I want to hide the command line log when connecting to Open VPN through a Python application, how can I do this?

`"--quiet"`
"--quiet" doesn't work